# Up upon the high mountain

Tags: riddle, word

> Where the high mountain shall remain I shall not.
>   Whether the shine is shiny enough I do not know but you seem to do so.

What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Riddles should generally be slightly longer than this, if you want you can extend it by clicking 'edit'

Comment: is it a stubborn goat?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a

> Shadow

Where the high mountain shall remain I shall not.

> The mountain casts a shadow upon the ground which moves with the sun.

Whether the shine is shiny enough I do not know but you seem to do so.

> The shadow doesn't know if there is enough light for it to be cast, but we do because we can see the shadow if there is enough light.